Is there any nonlinear function $f(x)$ for which both $\sin (f(x))$ and $\cos(f(x))$ have closed-form integrals?
I'm interested in closed-form antiderivaties of elementary functions.
The question arises from seeing that something as simple as $\int\sin(x^2)dx$ and $\int\cos(x^2)dx$ generates the Fresnel integrals.
I'm familiar with integration of elementary functions that yields elementary functions again.

Sure, take $f(x) = \arcsin x$ or variations of this.

@QiaochuYuan Thanks! Indeed. Both arcsin / arcos have derivative which is never zero. Is there any function f(x) whose derivative can be 0 somewhere and  still gives a closed form integral?

@QiaochuYuan can you put your comment as an answer? I'd like to mark it as solved

Yes.
There are a lot of functions that satisfy this condition.
We have:
$$\sin(f(x))=-\frac{1}{2}ie^{if(x)}+\frac{1}{2}ie^{-if(x)},$$
$$\cos(f(x))=\frac{1}{2}e^{if(x)}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-if(x)}.$$
We see, the right-hand sides of these formulas differ from each other only in the constants. The antiderivative of a product of a constant factor and a non-constant term is the product of the constant factor and the antiderivative of the non-constant term. If $\sin(f(x))$ has an antiderivative in closed form, $\cos(f(x))$ also has an antiderivative in closed form therefore which differs only in the constant factors - and vice versa. That means $\sin(f(x))$ has an antiderivative in closed form iff $\cos(f(x))$ also has an antiderivative in closed form.
The antiderivative of a sum is the sum of the antiderivatives of its summands. We therefore only need to determine the antiderivatives of $e^{if(x)}$ and $e^{-if(x)}$.
Also for elementary $f(x)$, the antiderivative of $e^{f(x)}$ is often not an elementary function. See e.g. in the references Smith and Conjectures 4 and 5 of Yadav.
Let's use therefore a simple way to find some elementary functions $f(x)$: we set $f(x)=-i\ln(g(x))$ and get $e^{\pm if(x)}=\pm g(x)$.
Because the antiderivatives of $e^{f(x)}$ often are nonelementary integrals, certain Special functions were introduced that are nonelementary antiderivatives of elementary functions. Examples are the following Liouvillian functions: elliptic integrals, logarithmic integrals, error function, Gaussian integrals, Fresnel integrals.
For deciding which kinds of functions can have a closed-form antiderivative, we also have the specialist area Symbolic integration with Liouville's theorem and Risch algorithm for elementary functions and Liouvillian functions.
You can play with functions at Wolfram Alpha.
$\ $
[Smith] TR Smith: List of Functions Without Antiderivatives
[Yadav 2012] Yadav, D. K.: A Study of Indefinite Nonintegrable Functions. PhD thesis, Vinoba Bhave University, India, 2012
[Yadav 2016-1] Yadav, D. K.: Six Conjectures in Integral Calculus. 2016
[Yadav 2016-2] Yadav, D. K.: Six Conjectures on Indefinite Nonintegrable Functions or Nonelementary Functions. 2016

Thank you so much, this is what I really needed to try to produce more cases

Here is a perhaps not-so-obvious example: let $f(x) = \ln(x).$ Then
\begin{align}
\int \sin(\ln(x))\,\mathrm dx &= -\frac12 x (\cos(\ln(x)) - \sin(\ln(x))) + C, \\
\int \cos(log(x))\,\mathrm dx &= \frac12 x (\sin(\ln(x)) + \cos(\ln(x))) + C. 
\end{align}

As mentioned in the comments taking $f$ equal to the inverse sine or cosine function works wonders. Here is another example.
Take $f(x)=x^2+1$ then
$$\int\sin(x^2+1)dx=\int \cos(1)\sin(x^2)+\sin(1)\cos(x^2)dx$$
Substituting in $u=\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{π}}$ makes it easy to see that
$$\int\sin(x^2+1)dx=\frac{\sqrt{π}(\cos(1)S(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{π}
})+\sin(1)C(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{π}}))}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$
Similarly we get that
$$\int\cos(x^2+1)dx=-\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\left(\sin\left(1\right)\operatorname{S}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\,x}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}\right)-\cos\left(1\right)\operatorname{C}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\,x}{\sqrt{{\pi}}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Where $C,S$ are the Fresnel integrals
Also notice that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)=2x$ , which is $0$ when $x$ is $0$ . So the answer to the question " Is there any function $f(x)$ whose derivative can be $0$ somewhere and still gives a closed form integral?" Is yes .
